# How to display No Value as text if Column value is DB Null in UI GRID

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-ng-if, ui-grid

How to show NO VALUE if column value is DB Null in angularjs ui grid. I tried using the code as below but it does not work. Am i missing anything.

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="row.entity.VariancePercentage>{{row.entity.VariancePercentage | number:2}}</div><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="!row.entity.VariancePercentage">No Value</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moved from comment)

I think your brackets/quotes are a bit unbalanced. Maybe this does the trick:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span ng-if="row.entity.VariancePercentage">{{row.entity.VariancePercentage | number:2}}</span><span ng-if="!row.entity.VariancePercentage">No Value</span></div>'
```